# Print an array variable with a loop

Tags: php

We have two array variables with names first_names and last_names that have an uncertain number of members. We intend to select an appropriate loop and only use the same information loop with the corresponding first and second variable information respectively.

You must use a loop.

```
<؟php
   $first_names=array('jack','root','admin');
   $last_names=array('jack111','root222','admin333'');


   foreach (array_combine($first_names ,$last_names) as $fname => $lname)
    {

      print_r($fname.$lname."<br>");

    };
?>
```

Comment: show your relevant code

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Simple n easy to understand

```
$first =count($first_names);
$last =count($last_names);

for($i=1;i<=$first;$i++)
 {
   echo $i;
 }
for($i=1;i<=$last;$i++)
 {
   echo $i;
 }
```